# invokeLater and the main class in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, program-entry-point, invokelater

I've been poking through the auto-generated code when making a new JFrame project with NetBeans, and came across this in my `main` method:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new TestClass().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

After some reading I've come to understand the need for invokeLater so the GUI components are handled in the EDT. That said, the line `new TestClass().setVisible(true);`, as it's implemented here, is a bit boggling to me. I get it in the context of creating a new instance...

```
TestClass tclass = new TestClass();
tclass.setVisible(true);
```

...but I don't quite follow what's going on in the `run()` method above. Is that code creating an anonymous class? I've run across that term but don't fully understand it yet. I assume it's not creating an instance in the "textbook" way I listed above because there's no variable (that I can see anyway) to refer back to that instance.

As an aside, it seems to me having your `main` method inside a JFrame class (or any GUI class, for that matter) isn't ideal anyway, so I'll probably move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new TestClass().setVisible(true)` is just creating a new instance, invoking `setVisible(true)` on it and then "forgetting" that instance by not saving a reference to it. It is actually equivalent to

```
TestClass tclass = new TestClass();
tclass.setVisible(true);
```

because the variable `tClass` is not accessible outside the run method and the run method does nothing but invoking `setVisible` on it.

If two or more (void) methods on the instance had to be called, you would *need* to use a variable to hold a reference to the instance, and you couldn't do the "one-line" trick that puzzeled you:

```
TestClass tclass = new TestClass();
tclass.setVisible(true);
tclass.methodX();
```

It is not an anynymous class (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) , it is something like an 'anonymous instance' although I don't think that term exists.

Depending on your project layout, it might make sense to move the `main` method to a separate class.

Comment: Ah, I think I follow you. Saving a reference to the class would be useless since it would be local to the run method anyway. The upshot of that then would be that if I need to access any instance variables in that class I'd need to create another instance of the class to do so. That seems inefficient.

Comment: Yes, I added an additional part to my explanation